# How to add checkboxes in Excel with radio button behavior?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

The objective is to make a survey like excel sheet, where the checkboxes can't be checked off for both the Passed and Failed buttons.
Can I program these checkboxes to have radio button behavior depending on its row?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same type of issue and this is what worked for me:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
       CheckBox2.Value = False
       CheckBox3.Value = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Check Box` or `Toggle Button`. You want to use `Option Button`.

See here:
https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-a-check-box-option-button-or-toggle-button-to-a-worksheet-HP010236677.aspx

Comment: I don't want to use an Option Button (aka Radio Button) I need blank to be an option too. So far Check Box is the best choice. I'm getting rid of the Not Tested Column. So when both Tested and Passed are unchecked, then it is Not-Tested. Radio Buttons won't allow you to have them both cleared.

Comment: You can do exactly what you want with Option Buttons. The buttons are tied to a cell. For 2 radio buttons, the value of the cell can be 0,1 or 2. You can set the initial state of both buttons to unchecked. This creates the initial 0 value which gives you your "Not-Tested" result. If the user clicks the first button, the cell value becomes 1. If they click the second button, the cell value becomes 2. So all three states are available to you using Option Button. If a user accidentally clicks a button, you can provide a reset button that sets both buttons back to unchecked (value = 0).